# Calendar input for dat.gui

Tags: dat.gui

Is there any way to have a Calendar input for dat.GUI? I'd like to be able to use the UI to input dates if possible. My work around is currently to enter the dates as Text, but I would prefer to have some type of calendar. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I know the question was asked sometime ago, but it hasn't been answered yet.  Out of a similar need, I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ubermario/pen/KeEgVN/) that demonstrates the integration of [jquery-simple-datetimepicker](http://mugifly.github.io/jquery-simple-datetimepicker/) with [dat.GUI](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md).  The pertinent section/logic follows:

```
    $(function(){

        //Create dat.gui instance
        var gui  = new dat.GUI({closeOnTop: true, width:450});

        var calendarFolder = gui.addFolder("Calendar");

        //Add calendarDate to dat.GUI
        var dateController = calendarFolder.add({Date: ""}, "Date");
        calendarFolder.open();  


        //Append Date Picker to calendarDate and show it.   
        var guiInput = $(calendarFolder.domElement).find("input").eq(0);

        //Create event handler to update the dat.GUI input element when calendar is hidden 
        var datePickerOptions = {"onHide": function(handler){ fnSetGuiDate(); } }; 

        //Add the calendar to the dat.GUI input element and immediately show it for demonstration 
        guiInput.appendDtpicker(datePickerOptions).handleDtpicker('show');

        //Initialize the dat.GUI input value
        fnSetGuiDate();

        function fnSetGuiDate() {
            var date = guiInput.handleDtpicker('getDate');
            var strDate =   date.getFullYear() + "-" + 
                            fnFormat(date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + 
                            fnFormat(date.getDate()) + " " + 
                            fnFormat(date.getHours()) + ":" + 
                            fnFormat(date.getMinutes());

            dateController.setValue(strDate);

            function fnFormat(mnthOrDate) {
                return mnthOrDate < 10 ? "0" + mnthOrDate : mnthOrDate;
            }

        }
    });
```